# Python + Minecraft Coordinates Trouble

Tags: python, coordinates, minecraft

The Y coordinate listed below teleports you to double what it's supposed to ingame. It is supposed to teleport you to 0, 62, 0, but it teleports you to 0, 124, 0

```
from mcpi.minecraft import Minecraft
mc = Minecraft.create()

x = 0
y = 62
z = 0

mc.player.setPos(x, y, z)
```

Comment: It doubles what?  What exactly is this supposed to do, and what does it do?

Comment: we need more clarification what the problem exactly is what the result is and what it should be.

Comment: @gerdadiegandalfziege I cleared it up more, apologies for not being specific enough.

Comment: and why not convert the bug into a feature and just half your input value y as a temporäry fix?

Comment: @gerdadiegandalfziege Because when I type 32, it gives me 98.

Comment: np that's why asked nobody is perfect keep it up everyone started small :)

Comment: Actually, 62 gave me 128.

Comment: Really that is weard. But I think I found the reason why can u plz give me the current player position?

Comment: I am currently at 0, 98, 0 and I attempted to use 32.

Comment: the result pos?

Comment: Also, if you found the answer, scroll down, and touch Answer Question

Comment: I need the starting and result pos so I can check if my theory is correct or wrong

Comment: Starting Position: 0, 66, 0. End position 0, 132, 0

Comment: and your value is 66 right ?

Comment: Yes. My Y value is 66 in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per comments on the [documentation](https://www.stuffaboutcode.com/p/minecraft-api-reference.html) for mcpi, it would appear that the coordinates are relative to the world spawn:

> getPos, getTilePos, setPos and setTilePos all appear to be relative to the player's spawn point at least in a single player world. I am going through trying to teleport my character but the coordinates I end up on are not the world's coordinates but a coordinate relative to where my character would spawn.

This appears to hold true with the results you observed, which were that different coordinate pairs produced a common difference in the expected and actual coordinates (i.e. `(0, 32, 0) (0, 98, 0)`; `(0, 62, 0) (0, 128, 0)`).

So, either fix an offset of 66 blocks into the y-axis values, or manually set the world spawn to `(0, 0, 0)` with `/setworldspawn`.

Comment: Thank you! This worked with no error!